# How to proceed with lagged variables and correlation matrix?

Tags: correlation, reporting

Would it be correct to report a correlation matrix with the variables not lagged when you use lagged variables to fit the model?

I think that you have to report the variables that you use in the model, but a work colleague "with level status" said that we have to report the correlation matrix with the variables not lagged...

I am not at a high level in statistics, so please bear with me.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to show.  If you are trying to illustrate to an audience why you used a lagged variable, it is good to show both.  If the un-lagged variable is not useful, then I would say there is no requirement per se to show it.  It is just helpful to see what you did.